# iPhone play caf audio backwards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, caf

I am writing an application in which I need to record audio and play it backwards.  I have recorded audio into a caf file using AVAudioRecorder and I have been able to play it forwards with both AVAudioPlayer and MPMoviePlayerController.  I tried setting the MPMoviePlayerController.currentPlaybackRate to -1 but it won't make any noise.  From researching I found that I will need to reverse the audio file byte by byte, but I am not sure how to do that.  Is there a way to read a caf file to an array and write from the array?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a sample app, which records what user says and plays them backwards. I have used CoreAudio to achieve this. [Link to app code](https://github.com/kiranb/iReversePlay).

As each sample is 16-bits in size(2 bytes)(mono channel)(this depends on what properties you have used for recording).
You can load each sample at a time by copying it into a different buffer by starting at the end of the recording and reading backwards. When you get to the start of the data you have reversed the data and playing will be reversed.

```
// set up output file
AudioFileID outputAudioFile;

AudioStreamBasicDescription myPCMFormat;
myPCMFormat.mSampleRate = 16000.00;
myPCMFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM ;
myPCMFormat.mFormatFlags =  kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
myPCMFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
myPCMFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
myPCMFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
myPCMFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
myPCMFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;


AudioFileCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)self.flippedAudioUrl,
                       kAudioFileCAFType,
                       &myPCMFormat,
                       kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                       &outputAudioFile);
// set up input file
AudioFileID inputAudioFile;
OSStatus theErr = noErr;
UInt64 fileDataSize = 0;

AudioStreamBasicDescription theFileFormat;
UInt32 thePropertySize = sizeof(theFileFormat);

theErr = AudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)self.recordedAudioUrl, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &inputAudioFile);

thePropertySize = sizeof(fileDataSize);
theErr = AudioFileGetProperty(inputAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &thePropertySize, &fileDataSize);

UInt32 dataSize = fileDataSize;
void* theData = malloc(dataSize);

//Read data into buffer
UInt32 readPoint  = dataSize;
UInt32 writePoint = 0;
while( readPoint > 0 )
{
    UInt32 bytesToRead = 2;

    AudioFileReadBytes( inputAudioFile, false, readPoint, &bytesToRead, theData );
    AudioFileWriteBytes( outputAudioFile, false, writePoint, &bytesToRead, theData );

    writePoint += 2;
    readPoint -= 2;
}

free(theData);
AudioFileClose(inputAudioFile);
AudioFileClose(outputAudioFile);
```

Hope this helps.